# breaking the dataframe and creating new columns for the broken chunks of data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data frame like this:

```
Values
1
2
3
.
.
1000
```

I want to break it into a data frame with 10 columns based on rows. So rows 1-100 goes in one column, rows 101-200 goes in the second column and so on resulting in the final data set as below:

```
Col1 Col2............... Col10
1    101                  901 
2    102                  902
3    103                  903
.     .
.     .
100  200                  1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
dfNew <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(df), 100))
names(dfNew) <- paste0("Col", 1:10)
```

The first line coerces the data.frame to a vector (`unlist`), then to a matrix with rows of length 100 (`matrix`). This matrix is then converted to a data.frame (`data.frame`).

Here are the first 6 rows:

```
 head(dfNew)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
1    1  101  201  301  401  501  601  701  801   901
2    2  102  202  302  402  502  602  702  802   902
3    3  103  203  303  403  503  603  703  803   903
4    4  104  204  304  404  504  604  704  804   904
5    5  105  205  305  405  505  605  705  805   905
6    6  106  206  306  406  506  606  706  806   906
```

The second line adds the data.frame names.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Values=1:1000)
```

Comment: it is funny, I always come across with your answers !!! I am really sorry I really don't mean to bother :-p I liked you answer , great and simple

Comment: @Learner If you figure out a different method to solve a problem, that's great. It's useful to show a multiple methods because some may work well in one situation, but less well in another.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the **do.call** which execute and construct a function call coming from *rbind* which takes a sequence of list consturcted by *lapply* arguments and combine it by columns

```
df <- data.frame(Values=1:1000)
mydf <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(df,matrix, ncol=10)))
names(mydf) <- paste0("Col", 1:10)
```

If you don't like to use **paste0** to set the column names, you can use **sprintf**

```
names(mydf) <-sprintf("Col%d", 1:10)

> head(mydf,5)
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
#1    1  101  201  301  401  501  601  701  801   901
#2    2  102  202  302  402  502  602  702  802   902
#3    3  103  203  303  403  503  603  703  803   903
#4    4  104  204  304  404  504  604  704  804   904
#5    5  105  205  305  405  505  605  705  805   905
```